# Receive text with ajax and mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, json, ajax, javascriptserializer

I have information that I sent with ajax jquery to a .net server but I can not receive the data as a parameter (any type) and modify it in memory and then convert it to json.
I will thank you for your help.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
document.querySelector('input#btnGuardar').onclick = function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = $('form#form_boleta').serializeJSON();
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "/Comprobante/Factura",
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result === "success") {
                        swal({
                            title: "¿Generar Otro Comprobante?",
                            text: "¡El comprobante se ha generado de manera correcta!",
                            type: "success",
                            showCancelButton: true,
                            confirmButtonClass: 'btn-success',
                            confirmButtonText: 'Si',
                            cancelButtonText: "No",
                            closeOnConfirm: false,
                            closeOnCancel: false
                        },
                            function (isConfirm) {
                                if (isConfirm) {
                                    self.parent.location.reload();
                                } else {
                                    window.location.href = "/Plataforma/Dashboard";
                                }
                            });
                    }
                    else {
                        var mensaje_error = document.getElementById('MensajeError');
                        //$("#MensajeError").fadeTo(1000, 1);

                        //$("#MensajeError").fadeOut(5000);
                        //return false;
                    }
                }
            })
        };
```

**CONTROLLER MVC .NET**

```
public JsonResult Factura(string[] json)//The json parameter appears as Null
        {
            string result;
            if (json != null)
            {
                //Modify the data received json.

                result = "success";
            }
            else
            {
                result = "error";
            }

            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first you must specify the name of the parameter to which you are sending the information in your **$.ajax** and parse object **"data"** to Json string

```
$.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/Comprobante/Factura",
            data: {json: JSON.stringify(data)},//JSON.stringify parse a object o json string
            dataType: 'json'
 })
```

second, in your controller MVC changes the type of parameter to a string and parse the string data to the type what you want.

```
public JsonResult Factura(string json)//The json parameter appears as Null
    {
        string result;
        string[] data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(json);
        if (data != null)
        {
            //Modify the data received json.

            result = "success";
        }
        else
        {
            result = "error";
        }

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, "Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.String[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly."